# Using maximum entropy for image classification of remotely sensed data

Tags: classification, geospatial, entropy, supervised-learning

I'm trying to understand how Maximum entropy would be used to classify pixel values in an image given some trained data. I need this to be explained to me in the lamest terms possible.

Comment: Have you tried looking for articles on this topic. I found http://www.is.tuebingen.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/MLSP2010-Erkan_6619%5B0%5D.pdf which seems to be exactly what you are looking for. Don't know if it fits the "lamest terms possible" criterion though...

Comment: Thank you. After taking a look at the link the description of the equations are still pretty complex for me. Over all I do understand the equation but what I don't understand is the process or methodology behind how it is applied to creating a classified image. I'm looking for more a a step by step example or explanation if that at all possible.

Comment: Frankly I doubt that a topic like this is explained somewhere in a step by step manner or without some weird looking math. One way to start is to split the topic you are asking about in several smaller topics (what is maximum entropy, what is image classification, what is remotely sensed data etc.). Working on the smaller pieces will give you some deeper understanding and after that you might be able to connect the bits and pieces together to get the bigger picture. I've read about this topic long time ago and this was one of the papers that gave me a nice overview.

Comment: Your right it isn't, or I just haven't found it yet. That,s why I'm looking for someone to give me a hand on here. I understand what entropy is and I understand what the equation does, I just need a better understanding of the process given an image array and some sample data derived from that array.